# Redirect not logged in users only on a specific page

Tags: wordpress

I want to redirect not logged in users in WordPress from page A to page B.

I've tried every answer on StackOverflow, but they were all written years ago and none of them works.

```php
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_to_specific_page' );

function redirect_to_specific_page() {

    if ( is_page('slug') && ! is_user_logged_in() ) {

        wp_redirect( 'http://www.example.com/sign-in/', 301 );
        exit;
    }
}
```

When added to functions.php nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function redirect_to_specific_page(){
    global $post;
    if ( !is_user_logged_in() && $post->ID == your page id ) {
       wp_redirect( 'http://www.example.com/sign-in/', 302 );
       exit;
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_to_specific_page' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong is your code. If you have specified "slug" correctly, your code should works. You can try following code also.

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'redirect_non_logged_users_to_specific_page' );

function redirect_non_logged_users_to_specific_page() {

if ( !is_user_logged_in() && is_page('add page slug or ID here') ) {

wp_redirect( 'http://www.example.dev/page/' ); 
    exit;
   }
}
```